# Disable and Enable ALL Hyperlinks using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below which disables all hyperlinks but after an event I want to enable them back all again, how can I do this?

```
$("a").click(function() { return false; });
```

I don't think its as simple as just setting it to true. ;)

Thanks all

Comment: All correct answers, but I had to give it to Pointy for pointing that tip out - no pun intended!

Comment: Will this take place frequently? As I understand it, binding/unbinding requires a bit of overhead. Depending on the page, may not be the best way to go.

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1771-Enable-And-Disable-jQuery-Event-Handlers-Rather-Than-Bind-And-Unbind-.htm

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of binding your "click" handler that way, do this:

```
$('a').bind("click.myDisable", function() { return false; });
```

Then when you want to remove that handler it's easy:

```
$('a').unbind("click.myDisable");
```

That way you avoid messing up other stuff that might be bound to "click". If you just unbind "click", you unbind everything bound to that event.

*edit in 2014* — the way you bind events now is with `.on()`:

```
$('a').on('click.myDisable', function() { return false; });
```

Probably it'd be better to do this:

```
$('a').on('click.myDisable', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

To unbind:

```
$('a').off('click.myDisable');
```

Finally, you could bind a handler to the document body and deal with `<a>` tags that are dynamically added:

```
$('body').on('click.myDisable', 'a', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

// to unbind

$('body').off('click.myDisable');
```

Comment: Thank you for that tip - I don't want to mess anything else up!

Comment: does binding a function that returns false stop any other bound handlers from executing after it? Don't you also need to stop the event propagation?

Comment: This is sort-of "cargo cult" but when I really want to kill the event I do: return !!event.stopPropagation() && false;

Comment: This works but it disables all click events of <a> tags not only their hyperlink function. I am finding a way to disable its link function but keeping its click function.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
// Better to use the live event handler here, performancewise
$('a').live('click', function() {... return false;});

// Now simply kill the binding like this
$('a').die('click');
```

bye

Comment: I had issues with using live() in IE9, and it's also deprecated - so consider using a different solution if you need to support IE9 or less.

Answer (score 5):

Binding and unbinding takes some overhead.

A different solution would be to add a class like `disabled`, then use `hasClass('disabled')` to test and see whether or not it should return `false`.

```
$('a').addClass('disabled');
$('a').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var disableLink = function(){ return false;};
$('a').bind('click', disableLink);
```

to restore:

```
$('a').unbind('click', dsiableLink);
```

Answer (score 4):

This replace all links on page to `#` which means: **disable links for other pages**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').attr('href', '#');
});
```

Comment: This one is better. It just disables the link, not the whole click event.

Answer (score 0):

You want to unbind the event: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to unbind it.

```
$("a").unbind("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could unbind the click handler:

```
$('a').unbind('click')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){


    $.myStopAnchor = function(){
      $stop = true;
    }

    $.myNoStopAnchor = function(){
      $stop = false;
    }

    $.myNoStopAnchor();

    $("a").click(function(ev) { 
       if ($stop){
         ev.stopPropagation()
       }
       return !$stop; 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even better, simply toggle the `display` of a large element with the high `z-index`. In the example below, the div covers the body.

```js
var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[2];
var noclick = document.getElementById('noclick');

link.onclick = function() {
  noclick.className = 'on';
}
```

```css
#noclick {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  /* Make sure this floats over content */
  z-index: 100; 
}

#noclick.on {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="noclick"></div>
  <a href="#">one</a>
  <a href="#">two</a>
  <a href="#">three</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Why the downvote without explanation? I have used this method in multiple situations with success. This answer is aligned with the question.

Comment: Please give an example how to do it.

Comment: @DEVELOPER Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Ricky B . Your suggestion proved to be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you strictly want the url to be inaccessible as well, you can remove `href` attribute from `a` tag. Something like that:

```
 $('a').removeAttr('href');
```

additionaly changing color of text and onhover cursor:

```
 $('a').css('color', '#333');
 $('a').hover(function () {
       $(this).css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
 );
```