# How can I disable all links when the browser is in full screen mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, fullscreen

How can I **disable** all links when the browser (Chrome / IE) is in `full-screen mode`?

Because when users click the link (www/pdf link) on my web page, he will redirect to another page that does not contain a **"Back"** button to go back to the previous page in full-screen mode. And the full-screen mode is required to access my web page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS3 fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen) to disable links.

PS: The above example won't work inside StackOverflow iframe. You need to copy code to a file then test it.

```css
:fullscreen a[href] {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Will be disabled on fullscreen</a>
<button onclick="document.body.requestFullscreen();">Go fullscreen</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Misir! However I cannot trigger the fullscreen css update by typing F11. Could we have another detection method in css / js?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to know the screen is in fullscreen or not...

```
if((window.fullScreen) ||
   (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height)) {
     //code goes here
} else {
     // Code goes here
}
```

you can override the onclick functionality of the anchor tag or remove the href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code to detect the fullscreen mode, then disable hyperlink.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if((window.fullScreen) || (window.innerWidth == screen.width && window.innerHeight == screen.height)) {
        // browser is fullscreen 
        console.log('fullScreen!');
        //disable hyperlink
        $('a').bind("click.myDisable", function() { return false; });
    } else {
        console.log('no fullScreen!');
    }
});
```

[Note] The above code uses window's resize event, you could also add the if condition statement in the page load event, to check whether the page is Fullscreen or not when page load.

More detail information about enable/disable hyperlink, please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202395/disable-and-enable-all-hyperlinks-using-jquery).